# How to visualize differences between groups based on category?

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization

I have two datasets of schoolchildren performance by height in cm, one for each school. I was wondering how to best visualize how the differences in the performance between the schools vary by grade. I was thinking of creating a regression for both school's performances, and graphing the differences between the two lines, but I'm not sure how rigorous or informative that would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is really abstract... I'd propose to try different visualizations and try to decide what exactly you want to show.

I leave here a small example that could be converted, as I think, to your needs (color = school, price = performance, carat = grade):

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(carat, price, color = color))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image]